# input value change detection using class

Tags: jquery

based in this question:

[Jquery input value change detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043440/jquery-input-value-change-detection)

i have `input 1` and `input 2` , with `value='100'`

if i change the `input 1` value, the alert show that the value was change, perfet.

but if i get in the input and lose the focus (i'm working with `focusout()`) again, the alert will keep showing that the value was changed again, maybe because i'm using a class.

i cant put this to work, what i'm missing ?

**html**:

```
<input type="text" value="100" class="inputTest" />
<input type="text" value="100" class="inputTest" />
```

**js:**

```
$(".inputTest").focusout(function(){
   if(this.value != this.defaultValue){
        alert('changed');
    } 
});
```

made a [**live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fJGqY/5/).

Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for `defaultValue()` and `val()`

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what the problem is. The alert will always fire if the value is different from 100. If you want to test if the new value differs from the previous one, you need a variable to hold the present value. Or you use a MVC Framework (if you're project is bigger and you need a lot of this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `data()` method to store the last value put into the `input`. You can then change your logic to test against this, rather than the default value.

```
$(".inputTest").each(function() {
    $(this).data("lastValue", this.value);
})

$(".inputTest").focusout(function() {
    if (this.value != $(this).data("lastValue")) {
        alert('changed');
        $(this).data("lastValue", this.value)
    }
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/fJGqY/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use the change handler instead of the focusout handler.  That way it will only check the values if the value was changed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you test for `value != defaultValue` on focusout, this will obviously never be true once the value has been changed once, until it is changed again.

You need to check whether `this.value != this.previousValue`, and store the previous value of the field in some way.

EDIT: @Rory McCrossan has described exactly how to do this in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

defaultValue will always contain 100. If you change the content of the input box, the defaultValue will not change.

Consider storing the previous value:

```
// Initialize previousValue
$(".inputTest").each(function () {
    $(this).data('previousValue', this.defaultValue);
});

$(".inputTest").focusout(function(){
   if(this.value != $(this).data('previousValue')){
        alert('changed');
        // Set previousValue again
        $(this).data('previousValue', this.value);
    } 
});
```