# ASP.NET Mvc Guid Parameter Binding Slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binding, guid

We are using MiniProfiler and on an action I noticed that before OnActionExecuting was called the time taken was between 75 and 150ms, the action was this:

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid guid, string fileName)
{
}
```

When I changed it to the following it dropped to 4ms.

```
public ActionResult Index(string guid, string fileName)
{
}
```

Has anybody else had these performance problems in Mvc with Guid binding?

Comment: I had a problem similar to this one that involves `Guid`s... http://stackoverflow.com/q/14961290/114029